# Laravel 4 autoload package not found? (Anvard oauth)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm simply following these instructions word by word:
    https://bitbucket.org/atticmedia/anvard

I added anvard to my dependency in autoload.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
            "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
            "atticmedia/anvard": "dev-master"
},
```

EDIT: changed the package name issue to the correct package: from "atticmedia-anvard": "*" to  "atticmedia/anvard": "dev-master".  (due to error in instructions on front page)

Running the command:

```
php composer.phar install
```

Returns an error of

```
Could not open input file: composer.phar
```

So instead I run the command

```
composer install
```

Which works just fine. EDIT:  After running composer dump-autoload, I now get this error:

```
 [RuntimeException]
 Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Atticmedia\Anvard\AnvardServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/litl.it/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 123
```

I next added

```
'Atticmedia\Anvard\AnvardServiceProvider',
```

to my to config/app.php (I removed the majority of the Illuminate files from the example just to save space in the example of how I inputted the new data, I didn't remove them from the actual file itself)

```
'providers' => array(
            'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
            'Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchServiceProvider',
            'Atticmedia\Anvard\AnvardServiceProvider',
            ),
```

After that, here is where my problem is, I run the command

```
php artisan config:publish atticmedia/anvard
```

And I get this error:

```
[RuntimeException]
Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Atticmedia\Anvard\AnvardServiceProvider' not found   in /var/www/litl.it/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 123
```

Confused where I went wrong, can someone help please?

EDIT:  I have tried

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Sadly it didn't fix my issue.

Comment: Have you tried running `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @that_guy Yes, when I was looking for similar questions problems on stackoverflow that was one of the solutions which I tried, the command works but it when I run php artisan config:publish atticmedia/anvard again after it, I get the same error.

Comment: Have you run composer update? or even check your vendor folder if the file is there?

Comment: Whats the output of the `composer install`?

Comment: @that_guy strange, it gives an error now:   [RuntimeException]
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Atticmedia\Anvard\AnvardServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/litl.it/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 123  (Progress maybe?)

Comment: @samayres1992 probably not. That error will go away if you remove the package from your providers.

Comment: in your question you wrote `atticmedia-anvard` instead of `atticmedia/anvard`.

Comment: @zwacky I just came across this about 10 minutes ago in the Anvard issues section, there's an error in the instructions on the front page.  "Add the dependency to your composer.json file: "atticmedia-anvard": "*"", strangely after I corrected the error, I'm still getting the same error, I have no clue where I'm actually going wrong anymore.  I think it's not loading the packages in to laravel correctly.

Comment: @samayres1992 you always need a vendor and a package name. the docs on the frontpage is wrong, it should be `"atticmedia/anvard": "dev-master"` (as you can see on packagist)

Comment: @zwacky I did make those appropriate changes, and sadly I have the same error.  Any further thoughts? (error:   [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                   
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Atticmedia\Anvard\AnvardServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/litl.it/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 123 )

Comment: @samayres1992 i tested it myself and it works perfectly. did you maybe put `"atticmedia/anvard": "dev-master"` into composer.json, added `"Atticmedia\Anvard\AnvardServiceProvider"` to the app.php and then `composer update`? if that's the case, remove the service provider entry in app.php and then do a composer update and put the service provider entry back in, as soon as you got the package via composer update.

Comment: You were right about that, I didn't remove "Atticmedia\Anvard\AnvardServiceProvider", I just gave it a try and the update was successful but I still get the same error when running php artisan config:publish atticmedia/anvard .. any further ideas? this error is stubborn.

Comment: @zwacky I managed to finally fix it, it seemed one of the commands I was running was resetting composer.json and removing anvard package.  Works fine, now, thank you for your help.

Comment: @that_guy Thank you, you solved my problem, I was unable to do it by using php composer.phar dump-autoload, but when I used composer dump-autoload every thing worked like a charm ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update the composer.json requirement according to the one listed on this page: https://packagist.org/packages/atticmedia/anvard and run `composer install` or `composer update` again.

I don't think the package is actually installed, since I doubt composer is able to find the correct package.

Comment: So are you recommending using "atticmedia/anvard": "dev-master" over "atticmedia/anvard": "*"  ?

Comment: Yes. The first part is whats used by composer to identify the package. You can use any version you need/like.

Comment: I just gave that a try, and I'm still receiving the same error. I did get this warning though, maybe this is the problem? Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.   (I tried this command to update it, composer update new/package)

Comment: try to remove your composer.lock file and the vendor folder. then run `composer install` again

Comment: I just tried your recommendation, and this is the resulting error http://cl.ly/image/1O2Q3s0Q2s3f/Image%202014-04-02%20at%2011.47.13%20AM.png (I thought a screenshot would be more readable)

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the instructions:

use:

```
"atticmedia/anvard": "dev-master"
```

then:

```
composer update
```

Be careful with self-updating composer if it's out of date, seems to edit the composer.json file and remove your packages.

Comment: self updating composer will not change your `composer.json`. Thing is `composer install` will not read the `composer.json` if there is a `composer.lock` present. `composer update` will read your `composer.json` and check for any new versions of the listed packages, then generate a new `composer.lock`.

You can read more here: http://adamcod.es/2013/03/07/composer-install-vs-composer-update.html